# Raster created by python GDAL interpreted upside down

Tags: python, raster, gdal

I am using CRS which has axis in left bottom corner. Code below produce Geotiff which is shown allright in QGIS but when I open it in other software it is upside down. Also gdal_calc takes it as upside down when calculating. Is there some easy way how to make sure this grid will be interpreted right as it is if I create it using gdal_translate from xyz?

```
geotransform=(min_x,min_cell_size,0,min_y,0,min_cell_size)
nrows,ncols = np.shape(zi)
output_raster = gdal.GetDriverByName('GTiff').Create(output_reaster,ncols, nrows, 1 ,gdal.GDT_Float32)
output_raster.SetGeoTransform(geotransform)
srs = osr.SpatialReference()
srs.ImportFromEPSG(28355)
output_raster.SetProjection(srs.ExportToWkt())
output_raster.GetRasterBand(1).WriteArray(zi)
```

Comment: The affine geotransform uses the upper left corner as the origin, this is typically minx, maxy. See:

http://gdal.org/gdal_datamodel.html

Comment: Not only that, but the last value in the geotransform tuple is usually negative because y decreases with increasing raster row.

Comment: @sgillies Thank you, I tried ...max_y,0,-min_cell_size before but so far I have 3 issues with that - 1st I prefer to write it CRS independent because I also sometimes use other CRS which has axis in left top corner. 2nd do I also need to revert lines bottom to top in zi? 3rd when changed to max_y and -min_cell_size my raster is shown in slightly different spot in QGIS - need to double check this again...

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/24055/raster-data-array-output-flipped-on-x-axis-using-python-gdal

Comment: @AndreJoost it looks similar though probably because of different wording I was not able to find that one. Also this issue is bit different because in my case file was displayed well in QGIS.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am not able to find some general solutions which would be CRS independent but for my case - axis in left bottom corner - the following changes works:

Start from max_y and use minus value for y cell size:

```
geotransform=(min_x,min_cell_size,0,max_y,0,-min_cell_size)
```

Revert the array lines from bottom to top:

```
zi = zi[::-1,:]
```

Will be glad if somebody come up with some CRS independent solution. Also when using this code I got often pop up window "python.exe has stopped working" on both my W7/64bit machines. The same happens when using gdal_calc. No idea why is that happening especially because it produces results and when the window is closed it continues without any issue...